# Can we switch ground in relay

Tags: relay, 12v, solid-state-relay

I am having a 3 pin relay used in bike horns. My need is to turn on and off ground using the positive as trigger. That means the positive terminal of the device is connected to the 12v supply. Usually we are turn on and off positive using ground. I need the opposite. Is it possible? If yes i can connect it to the device. I don't have any test environment. So i have to confirm before going forward.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks like a good question but could you clarify what you mean with "the opposite"?

Comment: Consider this as a digital way. Usually the trigger signel will be groud which is came from the horn switch. But here i have 12v supply as the switch. I have to control the ground connection of the circuit. @pipe

Comment: Applying voltage to the coil is all that matters. Whether the operator is switching the ground or switching the 12V, the coil couldn't care less.

Comment: @mike did you mean, I have to connect  ground at 86 an positive trigger at 85 and out put is taken from 87 will work as i expected

Comment: @mike65535: While the coil itself may not care about polarity the contact which shares one of the coil connections will.

Comment: After your edit you still have "*Usually we are turn on and off positive using ground.*" What does this mean? "*I don't have any test environment.*" You supplied a photo of the relay in your hand. All you need is a car battery and a horn and you have your test environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Table 1. Pin functions*

```
 Terminal/Pin number
 85 Coil
 86 Coil
 87 Normally Open (NO)
```

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZeeDM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Using a 3-pin, 12 V relay to use a switched positive signal to control a switched negative load.*

For more on auto relays see [12 volt planet](https://www.12voltplanet.co.uk/relay-guide.html).

Comment: Good answer, but I think the Op wants to switch to ground, so 86 would go to +12 and the switch and horn in your example go from 85 and 87 to the vehicle ground. Either would work well.

Comment: Thanks, Jack. I read "*My need is to turn on and off ground using the positive as trigger.*" five times before I answered. Let's see what the OP says.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a **low side switch** and is very common in automotive and industrial systems.  There also exists smart IC switches in automotive to do the same with protection.

Switching power is called a High side switch.

Comment: Can i work the above rely like that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have one side of the horn permanently connected to negative ground (so just one wire comes from the horn). The below paragraph is based on that assumption.

So you should connect pin 86 to +12, pin 87 to the horn wire, and to make the horn beep, you ground pin 85. If you have only a positive signal for "horn" then you can add a small 12V relay to operate the horn relay or add a transistor (and a resistor and a flyback diode). Otherwise there is no way to do it with a 3-pin relay as shown.

Comment: did you mean  Transistor's answer won't work?

Comment: Transistor's answer will certainly work fine if one side of the horn is not required to be connected to chassis ground.

Comment: Will the chasis ground connected in 86 will  act as the chasis ground at 87 when we connect 12v at 85?

Comment: If I understand your question, if the horn is grounded on one side and connected as you suggest, the relay will not perform any useful function and the full current of the horn will have to come from the input. In which case you may as well throw out the relay.

Comment: I mean horn ground is connected to 87. Chasis ground is connected to 86. So my question is can i get the exact  chasis ground at 87.

Comment: @KIRANKJ: Read the comments carefully. Everyone is confused whether your horn is permanently connected to +12 with switched negative (as in my answer) or permanently connected to ground (chassis) with switched positive. Please edit your question to make it very clear.